# Using Keras with Tensors instead of Vectors

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I realize this might be kind of a basic question, but due to the relationship between Keras and Tensorflow, it makes this question very hard to google for.

I have data for which each row is a 5 x 5 (columns x width rows) tensor, and I need the output to be a 2 x 5 tensor. I realize this is probably pretty basic, but any time I search for anything with "tensor" and "keras" in the title, it ends up being about using tensorflow, and much more complicated than what I am trying to do.

How do I set up the layers, both on input and output?

Thank you.

Comment: If you replace the word "tensor" with "image" in your question, do you see any major difference? You basically want to take an image as input and predict an image.

Comment: I do find more results, but all of these are related to convolutional neural networks. I'm looking to do regression, not classification, and I'm not sure how convolutional layers will affect my prediction process given the transformations they perform on the data.

Comment: CNNs have no problem doing regression.

Comment: Right, but how do I set up a convolutional neural net that doesn't convolute? If all the instructions include a step that I don't want to include, and it's necessary (at least for the tutorials being done), it's not helpful for me. I 100% don't understand how to set the layers up differently.

Comment: I think you need to reformulate your question to tell us what you want to do. Which kind of layers do you intend to use? What are they going to do?

Comment: More precisely, how do you know a CNN wouldn't work if you haven't tried? CNNs are known to do exactly what you want (look at autoencoders and GANs).

Comment: I will second Daniel's question, it is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. You want to turn a 5x5 matrix into a 2x5, but how do you want to do that? What is the expected result? What operations do you intend to do to convert?

Comment: I am doing a simple regression problem. Currently I have it working with doing each width-row individually as a row. That is, I'm taking a 5x1 row and using regression layers to eventually turn it into a 2x1 row. I think it's losing some of the subtleties of the transformation and how individual rows are related to each other, so I'm trying to do it with tensors instead.

@MatiasValdenegro It's mostly that the types of convolutional layers that I've used in the past were to reduce image size (e.g. 3x3 conversion on MNIST) which I do not want.

Comment: Convolution doesn't have to reduce image size.